# android use always post request insted of get

Tags: java, android, http, request

I am working on a project and I have a problem with send get request
I use

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setDoOutput(false);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("x-access-token" , token);
connection.connect();
```

URL Connection in android and any time I want send get request 
it just send post request what is the solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using [Apache library](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html) instead.